# Which registry / environment (or other) settings does urllib2.urlopen use to determine proxy settings?

Tags: python, networking, urllib2, urlopen

Following on from this question: [What is causing urllib2.urlopen() to connect via proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218809/what-is-causing-urllib2-urlopen-to-connect-via-proxy)

I'd like to know which operating system & environmental settings can affect urllib2.urlopen?

For example, I've noticed that on some machines within our very large corporation urllib2.urlopen insists on connecting via a proxy. This is a problem because the resources our application needs to connect to are on the local network, and so adding the proxy to the mix causes authentication problems.

I'm using Windows 32bit XP / Python 2.4.4

Comment: I think the culprit is the system's network setting. Did you try to check IE's options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the [exact code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r244/Lib/urllib.py?annotate=HEAD#l1244), but as the docs say the registry section is Internet Settings:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Comment: Next question - is there a way to make urllib2 ignore this setting? I want it to always connect directly (no matter what).

Comment: @Salim, is there an issue with the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218809/what-is-causing-urllib2-urlopen-to-connect-via-proxy/4218924#4218924) given at the other question?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to use Distribute to install some eggs within a coprporate ntwork. Ideally I'd not like to change the source code for Distribute (we'd prefer to keep it standard) - I'm looking for a way to force distrubute not to use a proxy with the minimum of hacking.